# How to pass array values(from multiCombo box) in routing to bind in another view in sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to pass the values of selected items from multiComboBox to another view to bind it in a table.
I am getting the selected values as

```js
selectedItems = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItems");
```

routing code:

```js
{
    "pattern": "data/{value}",
    "name": "page2",
    "target": "page2"
}
```

```js
oRouter.navTo("page2", {
value : JSON.stringify(selectedItems)
}
```

and getting it in another controller as:

```js
var output = JSON.parse(oEvent.getParameters("arguments").value);
alert(output);
```

The error I am getting is 
**Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

Comment: `selecteditem` is a nested object, might contain methods too. it will contain itself, somewhere in there by the sound of things. look inside it in the debugger to see the values you need.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the fact that the `selectedItems` parameter of the [selectionFinished](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.MultiComboBox/events/selectionFinish) event is actually an array of [sap.ui.core.Item](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.Item/overview). Most UI5 elements are not serializable, because they hold references to their parents, which in turn hold references to the elements themselves (thus forming a cycle).

In my opinion, you should instead use the selected keys instead of the selected items. You can obtain the keys by simply using the [getSelectedKeys](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.MultiComboBox/methods/getSelectedKeys) method:

```
var aKeys = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedKeys();
```

This will return an array of strings, which can be then serialized as you intended. After deserializing the keys, you can use the `setSelectedKeys` method to restore the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to pass the data by setting it in a Global Model instead of passing it as router string. Just my 2 cents. :)